# Running Cisco VPN Client after Windows 10 November Update

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn, windows-10

I had installed Cisco VPN Client so that I could connect to my client's VPN, and this was working great on Windows 10 (after many hacks) until the Windows 10 November update, which automatically uninstalled Cisco VPN Client, accompanied by a dialog saying that this program is no longer compatible with Windows 10. (By the way, I find it pretty outrageous that they would automatically uninstall programs now in windows updates.)

When I try to reinstall Cisco VPN Client, it says "This app can't run on this PC. Cisco VPN Client doesn't work on this version of Windows. Learn more." The learn more link doesn't give any useful information.

I have a PCF file that I had imported into Cisco VPN Client to setup the connection, so I can't just switch to another VPN client unless it supports PCF. I read about the Shewsoft client as an alternative that can import PCF files, however this doesn't install on Windows 10 either (it says not compatible.)

So how can I use VPN now? I seem to be completely blocked...